# Excel VBA - move selected listbox items to range

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, range

I got a question about moving a listbox item (multiple columns) to a certain range in a worksheet. I can do it all complicated with a lot of code so I've got the following piece of code but I'd like to make it quicker and easier if that's possible.

I've got a formula in a worksheet called Start which is cell A9, the first line to be filled is A10 then.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Start").Offset(1,0)=me.listbox1.list(0,0)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Start").Offset(1,1)=me.listbox1.list(0,1)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Start").Offset(1,2)=me.listbox1.list(0,2)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Start").Offset(2,0)=me.listbox1.list(1,0)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Start").Offset(2,1)=me.listbox1.list(1,1)
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Start").Offset(2,2)=me.listbox1.list(1,2)
```

In this example it's a listbox with 3 columns and 2 selected items, but in reality I have 7 listbox columns and dozens of lines, so this would cost a lot of code...

If it's possible I would like to skip columns in the sheet, so instead of item1 moving to A10-A16 I would like A10, C10, E10, etc. Don't ask me why and if that's not possible that's good too!

Please help! Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in a loop

For intRow = 1 to lastrow

For intCol = 0 to 6

```
  Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Start").Offset(intRow,intCol)=me.listbox1.list(intRow - 1,intCol)
```

next intCol

For intRow

Comment: And do I have to dim intRow and intCol both as long?

Comment: only if you plan on exceeding 65,000 odd row or columns. if not sure then it wont hurt either. :-)